Returning to list view after executing a custom button implementing apex class
I have a custom button on my list view whose source is a visualforce page. The visualforce page executes an apex class which updates certain records based on a field values on load using action attribute. I am not passing any records to the visualforce page. My requirement is to return (or redirect) to the specific list view from which the button was clicked and for the list view to show the updated values after running apex class.
I have referred to this post
Calling Apex Class from Custom Button, And Then Refreshing List View but the approach is giving me a cross domain cookies error.
I also tried giving a button on the vf page like <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!list}"/> But on clicking it I am taken to the listview before it is updated.

This question is similar to: Calling Apex Class from Custom Button, And Then Refreshing List View. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have actually used the approach mentioned there. But it is raising a cross domain cookies problem. I want to redirect to the same list view without any button on the vf page. Is there any up to date approach to do the same?

You can try a workaround. Hiding the list from UI using flag. Empty the data list and fill again. Then enable the flag to show the list in UI.
